# How to make odometer scrolling numbers on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, odometer

I have the odometer js implemented on the stats of the website I have. The animation for the stats is already there. when you scroll down it looks good and is animated, but then it plays once and stops.

I want to repeat the scroll effect on each number individually every time someone hovers. Can anyone help me with this? Your help on this will be hearty appreciate.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Odometer number rolling
    window.onload = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        const odometerElements = document.querySelectorAll('.odometer');
        odometerElements.forEach((element) => {
          const targetValue = element.getAttribute('data-value');
          const odometer = new Odometer({
            el: element,
            value: 0,
            format: '(,ddd)',
            duration: 18000,
          });
          odometer.update(targetValue);
        });
      }, 150);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="company-statistics">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="stats-wrapper">
      <div class="stats-content row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="13">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="10">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="75">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="18">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="22">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-xl-none stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="45">0</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example to replicate this maybe on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't have any replica of this at the moment but will surely provide one once I make it, maybe on codepen OR this Jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the odometer rolling create a function `odo_roll()` and run it on hover with

```
$(".odometer").hover(function() {
   odo_roll();
});
```

But since the odometer will only roll if its value is not the target value, you need to somehow change the initial value. Random numbers seem a good choice:

```
odometer.update(rnd(10, 99));
```

What might also be causing trouble in your code is the fact that it's using `window.onload` after `$(document).ready()` but when the DOM is ready the `window.onload` event has already fired.

See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Quote:

> Although handlers added by `.ready()` will always be executed in a
> dynamically loaded script, the window's load event has already
> occurred and those listeners will never run.

#### Working demo

```js
function rnd(minVal, maxVal) {
  var randVal = minVal + (Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal));
  return Math.round(randVal);
}

function odo_roll() {
  const odometerElements = document.querySelectorAll('.odometer');
  odometerElements.forEach((element) => {
    const targetValue = element.getAttribute('data-value');
    const odometer = new Odometer({
      el: element,
      value: 0,
      format: '(,ddd)',
      duration: 18000
    });
    odometer.update(rnd(10, 99));
    odometer.update(targetValue);
  });
}

//Odometer number rolling
window.onload = setTimeout(odo_roll, 150);


$(".odometer").hover(function() {
  odo_roll();
});
```

```css
.odometer {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/odometer.js/0.4.7/odometer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/odometer.js/0.4.7/themes/odometer-theme-train-station.css">
<section class="company-statistics">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="stats-wrapper">
      <div class="stats-content row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="13">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="10">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="75">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="18">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="22">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-xl-none stat-item">
          <div class="odometer" data-value="45">0</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, This function does work, but all the numbers and stats are start scrolling, where else I want to scroll individually on hover.

Comment: @PrashantJani you need to change the function `odo_roll` to run for the current target because as it is it select all odometers (`const odometerElements = document.querySelectorAll('.odometer');`)